# Going to Another viewcontroller from OverlayView of camera

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am building an Iphone app where i have placed a overlay view with few buttons on top of camera view,clicking on the button should take to a viewcontroller which has MapView. I am facing issues in 2 things

1) How to go to MapView ViewController on button click from camera overlayview?
2) Is there a way i can place same overlay view on top of mapview.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

for this **1) How to go to MapView ViewController on button click from camera overlayview?** you need to dismiss the camera view and present the MAP view as modal .

Comment: on going to mapview from on clicking a button on cameraview overlay, the mapview zoom,scrolling and annotations are not functioning. can some please help in figuring out why is it happening like that.